# Does XQuery (or XPath) have equivalents to Update, Insert, and Delete as well as Select?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I know how to find what I need from XML using XPath.  The syntax takes a little getting used to, but it is quite powerful.  I'm interested in learning XQuery also, but the SQL like syntax seems awkward.  Even so, if it can provide not just a select equivalent, but also update, insert, and delete as SQL does, I will forgive all awkwardness.

So, does XQuery have equivalents to Update, Insert, and Delete as well as Select?

Does XPath have these equivalents that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. None of [**XPath**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) or [**XQuery**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/) has SQL-like update/insert/delete functionality.

You need to look for an implementation of the "[**XQuery 1.0 Update Facility**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/)".

At this moment (Nov. 2008), three such are known:

1. [**SaxonSA XSLT and XQuery Processor**](http://www.saxonica.com/) — by [**Michael Kay**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Kay_(software_engineer)); Supported since version 9.1, but only in the commercial version.
2. [**MonetDB/XQuery**](http://monetdb.cwi.nl/XQuery/) - An open source XQuery processor on top of the [**MonetDB**](http://monetdb.cwi.nl/Home/index.html) relational database system.
3. [**XQilla**](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/) - An open source ([ASL2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)) XQuery processing library with support for the latest XQuery Update features. XQilla is written in C++ and includes a command line executable shell to execute queries against XML content stored on a local filesystem. This library is actively developed and part of a supported Oracle product, [Berkeley DB XML](http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/xml/).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Sure, but in 2008 I believe BaseX still wasn't around.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the [XQuery Update Facility](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/), check out the [XQuery Use Cases](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10-use-cases/) or check out the [XML Query working group](http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/) page.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server 2005/8 the extension of XQuery is called [XML DML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177454.aspx), and supports data modification using the [replace value of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx) statement.

Answer (score 4):

XPath is a language for addressing parts of an XML document. So it cannot have any DML statement. It is select statement by definition.

Comment: That's true for XPath. XQuery, however, does have a formally standardized extension which allows updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `update` operation with [`BaseX`](https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#DELETE) with [xquery](/questions/tagged/xquery):

```
$ cat xquery.txt 
declare namespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
copy $input := doc("/dev/stdin")
modify delete node $input//w:rPr
return $input
```

```
$ cat file3.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="0">
      <w:rPr>
          TO REMOVE
      </w:rPr>
      <w:rPx>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol" w:hint="default"/>
      </w:rPx>
    </w:lvl>
</root>
```

```
$ basex xquery.txt < file3.xml 
<root xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:lvl w:ilvl="0">
    <w:rPx>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol" w:hint="default"/>
    </w:rPx>
  </w:lvl>
```